# How to make search bar shrinking effect like default mailbox

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

How make animation like ios  default mail. I need the same effect like search bar is hide at initial and when i drag table view download the it shows the search bar.

like in the screenshot

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

update to the question.- Right now i am using a searchBar above tableview in the view controller.

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        workActivityTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        workActivityTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: controller.searchBar.frame.height)
        navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

        return controller
    })()
```

Comment: Try this: `self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)`. Put this line of code to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: thansk for your response. But Right now i am using a searchBar above tableview in the view controller. Is it works with that too. As search bar is totally seperate with tableView and i want to show search bar when user swipe tableview downward.

Answer (score 1):

Drag `search bar` in to your tableview in your storyboard as it should be the first subview of your tableview!

Tableview will consider it as a header.

Your view hierarchy will be look like,

[image]

And the default size of search bar will be `44`.

Now in your `viewDidload` set content offset of your table view like,

```
_tblView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);
```

or in swift you can say,

```
tblView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44)
```

and you're done!

bellows are screenshot of results,

Initially

[image]

After scroll

[image]

This will not work if `prefersLargeTitles` set to `true` then initially you will get search bar!

Comment: it is not giving the same animation effect to show or hide search field as in Mail app of ios

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add the search bar as a `tableHeaderView` to your tableView, and in your `viewDidLoad`, add the following lines:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = your_searchbar
tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: your_searchar.frame.height)
navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

UPDATE:

This can be easily achieved by adding the search controller as a part of `navigationItem`. Something like this:
`self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

This is available from iOS 11.

Comment: thanks for your response. But Right now i am using a searchBar above tableview in the view controller. Is it works with that too. As search bar is totally seperate with tableView and i want to show search bar when user swipe tableview downward.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Have you added the search bar through `storyboard`?

Comment: Okay, I suggest to use `tableView` because the frameOffset are handled more easily and with very few boiler plate code you can get the search bar to work and more or less it functions the same way as adding it above the `tableView` through the storyboard.

Comment: I used the same as you suggested and updated the code in question. But the animation of showing and hiding the search bar when user do tableview scroll up and down is not same as in the mail app.